Issue with shower suddenly increasing in pressure and losing temperature
So my mains connected shower does this odd thing where it will run normally for 2 or 3 minutes, then suddenly the pressure will rise and the water will go cold for 30 seconds, before returning to a normal temp and pressure for three minutes, then go cold again etc etc. This is nothing to do with toilets or other outlets being used, it is too regular.
Things to consider:
*If the temperature mixer is on full heat the problem does not occur. It only happens when the mixer is turned down slightly beyond that point.
*We have a combi boiler
*this issue only affects the shower - all other HW taps run from the same boiler and aren't affected.
*The shower is a thermostactic mixer and the whole unit was replaced due to this issue, but this didn't help
*If you drop the shower head below the level of the inlet to the thermostatic mixer unit the issue doesn't manifest
*Exchange plate in boiler was recently replaced.
It feels like there might be an issue with the cold water pressure struggling to overcome a blockage, but when it reaches a critical point it overwhelms the thermostatic mixer. Any sense in this?

I'm pretty certain this has been discussed here before, and the issue turned out to be the boiler cutting out repeatedly when only a little hot water was being used (because it can't turn down any lower)

@ChrisH thanks, that makes sense. Can this be remedied? I had a look at your previous comments and there wasn't a permanent solution. I will try running a hot tap while showering to see if that helps. Would increasing cold flow to the boiler help, in that I will also need to increase hot flow too?

I've never lived with a combi, so I'm no expert.  There may be some boiler settings you can adjust, or increasing the flow from the shower was suggested.  That would probably be enough as that's what you're doing by lowering the showerhead

Thanks, I just increased the temp setting on the mixer and this seems to have helped.
